# Compile error with EasyBMP library

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a program that can rotate a given BMP file 180 degrees and create a new BMP file with the rotated image. I'm using the EasyBMP library. However, every time I try to compile, I get these warnings:

```
EasyBMP Warning: Attempted to access non-existent pixel (359, 236);
                 Truncating request to fit in the range [0,358] x [0,269].
```

And I get hundreds of these! (The image in question is 359x270) The weird thing is that my code actually works 100%. When I run the program, it does create a rotated image and looks perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If should be

```
for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        color = in(x, y);
        *(out(width - x - 1, height - y - 1)) = *color;
    }
}
```

(Note `<` instead of `<=` and `- 1` added).

Comment: Why should the -1 be there though?

Comment: Same reason as for `<` instead of `<=`. Correct values are `0` through `width - 1` inclusively, but `width - 0` (given x == 0 in this iteration) gives `width` which is out of bounds.